# Why the result of encode_base64 doesn't correspond to decode_base64?

Tags: perl

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("syn_ack@163.com");'
c3luX2Fjay5jb20=
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64("c3luX2Fjay5jb20=");'
syn_ack.com
```

The encode result cannot decode to original string, why?

Comment: Use `use strict; use warnings;`, especially during debugging!

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `@` as `\@`or use different quotes.
This is because double quotes are expanded, and `@163` is treated as an array `@163` (even if this name is not valid identifier).

This works as expected:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e "print encode_base64('syn_ack@163.com');"
c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t

perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("syn_ack\@163.com");'
c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t

perl -MMIME::Base64 -e "print decode_base64('c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t');"
syn_ack@163.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the quotes. Perl will interpolate variables when using double-quotes.

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e "print encode_base64('syn_ack@163.com');"
c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e "print decode_base64('c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t');"
syn_ack@163.com
```

http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html

Answer (score 1):

When you see unexpected results with Perl, make sure warnings are enabled.

```
$ perl -w -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("syn_ack@163.com");'
Possible unintended interpolation of @163 in string at -e line 1.
c3luX2Fjay5jb20=
```

No interpolation occurs inside single-quoted (`''`) strings, so you could run

```
perl -w -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64('syn_ack@163.com');'
```

or leave the double-quotes (`""`) and escape the `@`

```
perl -w -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("syn_ack\@163.com");'
```

Either outputs

```
c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t
```

Decoding gives

```
$ perl -w -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64("c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t");'
syn_ack@163.com
```